# Labeling each bar in a multiindex grouped, stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart, multi-index

I would like to figure out how to label each bar of a grouped bar plot with its category name. My dummy dataframe looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Product', 'StId', 'DJF', 'MAM', 'SON'],
                  data=[['Model1', EBBR, 200, 500, 100],
                        ['Model2', EBBR, 150, 630, 50],
                        ['Model3', EBBR, 73, 189, 200],
                        ['Model4', EBBR, 200, 350, 600])
```

Then I get the plot I want by unstacking and plotting like this:

```
df["Product"] = pd.Categorical(df["Product"], ordered=True, categories=df["Product"].unique())                   
df.set_index(['Product', 'StId'], inplace=True)
df0 = df.reorder_levels(['StId','Product']).sort_index()

df0 = df0.unstack(level=-1) # unstack the 'Product' column
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_width = 0.1
(df0['SON']+df0['MAM']+df0['DJF']).plot(kind='barh', width=bar_width, color='#6495ED', edgecolor='k', rot=0, ax=ax)
(df0['DJF']+df0['MAM']).plot(kind='barh', width=bar_width, color='#EEAD0E', edgecolor='k', rot=0, ax=ax)
df0['DJF'].plot(kind='barh', width=bar_width, color='#66CD00',edgecolor='k', rot=0, ax=ax)
```

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to label each bar with its categorical name (e.g. Model1, Model2, etc). I want the labels at the end of each bar, not on the y-axis. Subsequently, other same structured dataframes for different StId's will be plotted on the same figure so ideally I would like my code to automatically label each bar of those as well.

Appreciate any help on this.

My plot currently looks like this:

[image]